# Empty - Transparent SSIS Toolbox

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I have install  Microsoft Visual Studio community editions 2019 and i m facing issues with the SSIS Toolbox, see image below.

Any suggestions?

[image: SSIS Toolbox]

Comment: Just a guess: Open Tools > Options, then Environment > General and disable "Optimize rendering for screens with different pixel densities".

Comment: @gdir thanks for the answer. It s exactly what i m looking for!

Comment: The same thing happens in the code metrics window. A fix for that is announced for the next update. I guess that it will fix the non visible text in the SSIS Toolbox as well.

Answer (score 0):

Open Tools > Options, then Environment > General and disable "Optimize rendering for screens with different pixel densities"